# Retrieve Azure Blob from custom node.js API

Tags: ios, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to retrieve the binary data of an image from a Microsoft Azure blob storage container.

I have successfully uploaded an image to a storage container on Azure from an iOS app using the following function on AZSCloudBlobContainer.

```
blockBlob.uploadFromData(imageData, completionHandler:
```

I can also successfully download it straight to the iOS app using the following function on AZSCloudBlob.

```
blockBlob.downloadToDataWithCompletionHandler({(error: NSError?, data: NSData?)
```

The problem I have is that I want to be able to retrieve the image from a node.js server side script, not directly from the app. Amongst others, I have tried the following code...

```
var containerName = 'containerName';
var blobService = storage.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey);
var blobName = 'blobname';
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');

blobService.getBlobToStream(containerName, blobName, stream, function (error, result, response2) {

        response.json(result);
    });
```

The response retrieves the blob information but I don't know how to get the actual binary data of the image?

```
({
blobType = BlockBlob;
container = containername;
contentLength = 14593;
contentSettings =     {
    contentType = "application/octet-stream";
};
etag = "\"0x8D********\"";
lastModified = "Mon, 05 Sep 2016 18:57:41 GMT";
lease =     {
    state = available;
    status = unlocked;
};
metadata =     {
};
name = "blobname";
requestId = "ce3e7************";
serverEncrypted = false;
})
```

I've tried many other avenues as well but I'm completely new to node.js and have spent far too much time trying to solve this, any direction would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Azure Mobile Apps in Node.js are based on [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/), whose `response` middleware is a kind of writable stream, you can leverage the function `getBlobToStream()` directly send the content stream to the client side. E.G.

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {
        var azure = require('azure-storage');
        var blobsrv = azure.createBlobService(
            '<storage_account>',
            '<storage_key>'
            )
        blobsrv.getBlobToStream('<container>', '<blob>', res, function (error, result) {})
    }
}
```

And you can test the functionality by browsing the custom api directly from browser via the URL of the api `http://<your_mobile_app_name>.azurewebsites.net/api/<api_name>`

Comment: I will mark this as correct as it answers the question perfectly, however the reason I wanted to do it server side was so I could return multiple blobs from a container (but not all). Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: You can try to generate multiple SAS Urls of the image blobs and the client side load the remote blobs on Azure Storage via these urls.